# How can I "hide" empty rows after I filter a Table?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a Search Bar that displays any match/query in a grid table below. This works fine, but the problem is that upon filtering the query, the Table will also display empty rows that I'd like to remove.

Example: I have a JSON with 10 datasets, so if a query matches 3 of the datasets, my table will display those 3 matches, and then 7 empty rows. See the picture below.

How can I remove empty rows on a grid table?

I'm using the sap.ui.table.Table library: [link](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Sorting/preview)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "empty" rows are visible due to the [visibleRowCount](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#getVisibleRowCount) attribute of the table control. You can update this dynamically each time your row binding changes by adding a handler for the change event of the binding. For example...

View:

```
<Table id="myTable" rows="{ path: '/rows', events: { change: '.onBindingChange' } }">
```

Controller:

```
onBindingChange: function(oEvent) {
    this.getView().byId("myTable").setVisibleRowCount(oEvent.getSource().getLength());
}
```

You can see a working (JavaScript) [example here](http://jsbin.com/wovesifecu/1/edit?js,output)

It may also be worth checking out [visibleRowCountMode](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html#getVisibleRowCountMode) which will allow you to control how the table handles visible rows.